# Covert a string into list & sublist with characters sepration in python

Tags: python, string, list

Covert a string `"Welcome to Baramati"` into list & sublist  (ex: 1st list has 3 letters `['W','E','L']`. The 2nd list has 4 letters `['C','O','M','E']` and the 3rd list has 5 letters & the 6th list has 6 letters.

Comment: What about the spaces? Should they be in the lists?

Comment: No space required only characters in that list

Comment: What about the last list when you run out of letters? You should specify all these obvious questions in your post. Also, you should post your own attempt, so helpers can see where you are stuck and approach you chose. Do not expect people to just write code for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know as I'm a beginner. Will take care of that for sure!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one implementation using `itertools.count`:

```py
import itertools

s = "Welcome to Baramati"
lst = [c for c in s if c != ' '] # list-ify

cnt = itertools.count(start=3)
output = []
while lst:
    output.append(lst[:(length := next(cnt))])
    lst = lst[length:]

print(output) # [['W', 'e', 'l'], ['c', 'o', 'm', 'e'], ['t', 'o', 'B', 'a', 'r'], ['a', 'm', 'a', 't', 'i']]
```

Apparently this also uses walrus operator `:=` , which is available in python 3.8+.

Also, this might be slightly less memory-efficient, because it makes a temporary list. But tbh I personally like to use `while something:` pattern. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator function and some [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import count, islice

def chunks(s, start=3):
    i = iter(s.replace(" ", ""))
    for c in count(start):
        if not (chunk := [*islice(i, c)]):
            return  
        yield chunk


[*chunks('Welcome to Baramati')]
# [['W', 'e', 'l'], ['c', 'o', 'm', 'e'], ['t', 'o', 'B', 'a', 'r'], ['a', 'm', 'a', 't', 'i']]
```